# Ansible shell command fails under sudo when it should succeed

Tags: centos, sudo, centos7, ansible

I have an Ansible task based on https://github.com/al3x/sovereign/blob/master/roles/tarsnap/tasks/tarsnap.yml#L2 that keeps failing when it should succeed.

I used to run the role with `ansible_ssh_user=root`, but recently switched to using a non-root user that has passwordless sudo rights and then calling [`become`](http://docs.ansible.com/become.html) in my playbooks.

However, now the Ansible task fails even though I've specified `become=true`. Tarsnap is already installed, but the task still returns `stderr: /bin/sh: tarsnap: command not found`. I think it's because of something around `sudo` that I don't quite understand.

When I manually ssh into the server as this non-root user and run `sudo tarsnap --version | grep 1.0.35 --color=never`, I get `sudo: tarsnap: command not found`. But if I SSH in as root, that same command gives me `tarsnap 1.0.35`. 
Similarly, when I run `sudo -i tarsnap --version | grep 1.0.35 --color=never` (note the **-i**), I get `tarsnap 1.0.35`.

I am using CentOS 7.

1) Why are the results different for `sudo` vs `sudo -i`?

2) How do I fix my Ansible task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point to tarsnap with a fully-qualified path, or set your PATH explicitly so it can find tarsnap.  You can find the missing path element by logging in as root and executing `which tarsnap`

You don't mention what flavour of Linux you are using, so bear in mind that /bin/sh may very well not be the same as /bin/bash (eg. ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile may not be read).

`sudo -i` will give you an 'interactive' shell. You should see the manual page for bash (if indeed you are using bash) to find out what 'interactive`means (ie. which files are consulted). I think you'll find that`sudo -i`will read in ~/.bashrc, while just`sudo`(without`-i`) will not.

Comment: Thanks, fully qualified fixed it. Using Centos 7. What's weird is if I do `sudo -i which tarsnap` I get `/usr/local/bin/tarsnap`; but then I run `sudo echo $PATH` and `:/usr/local/bin:` is part of the path so I don't get why a normal non-interactive `sudo` can't find tarsnap since it should be checking that path.

Comment: Please show a verbatim transcript of how you determined what PATH was.

Comment: 1) SSH in as my non-root user. Using the default CentOS bash shell. 2) Run `sudo echo $PATH` 3) Result: `/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/non-root-user/.local/bin:/home/non-root-user/bin` <-- result contains `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thought so. The shell is interpreting `sudo echo $PATH` before sudo is run. Change the `$PATH` to `\$PATH`